# What does !FILTERs mean?

Tags: java, object, web-crawler, crawler4j

I have recently implemented [Crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/) and I am trying to teach myself the code by breaking it down line by line. I am having trouble understanding what the !FILTERS object on the line of code below means.

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
            String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
            return !FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() && href.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");
    }
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone helped me understand !FILTERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a negation of a condition... You should read it like this:

```
! ( FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() ) [...]
```

Basically, if the filters don't match the href, AND that the href starts with "http://www.ics.uci.edu/", that function would return true.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite value of `FILTERS.matcher(href).matches()`. basically exclamation point is also called `negate` sign.

if this condition: `FILTERS.matcher(href).matches()` returns true, it changes it to false.